# spring-boot 1.2.0.M2 breaks app

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot app that worked fine up until I updated from 1.2.0.M1 to 1.2.0.M2. The app will not build because of an UnsatisfiedDependencyException resulting from spring-boot RabbitAutoConfiguration:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
    Error creating bean with name 'jmsMessagingTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$MessagingTemplateConfiguration.class]: 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate]: :
    No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate] is defined: 
    expected single matching bean but found 3: looperTemplate,pingTemplate,orgRequestTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
    No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate] is defined: 
    expected single matching bean but found 3: looperTemplate,pingTemplate,orgRequestTemplate
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:466) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
```

The problem is I do have RabbitMQ templates, but I have 3 of them and it needs a qualifier to select a single template. However this code is in spring-boot, not my code. I would prefer not to have to alter spring-boot code, but I am not sure what I should do in my code to prevent this exception.

I can see the offending jmsMessagingTemplate was added in the 1.2.0.M2 version. The naming of this is also misleading as I do not have JMS enabled in my app (although this is a RabbitMQ specific auto configuration file in spring-boot).

Any suggestions on how I can configure my code without eliminating templates or modifying spring-boot code?

Comment: Don't you need to mark one of your templates as `@Primary`?

Comment: I have an ugly workaround for my problem by simply renaming one of the templates to "jmsMessagingTemplate". This allows my code to work and does not change any of the spring-boot code. This still begs the question of how I should properly fix this problem. I suppose I could also add an unused template name "jmsMessagingTemplate" to satisfy the RabbitAutoConfiguration dependency, but this seems wrong also.

Comment: How do I mark a template as @Primary when it is only defined in the xml configuration? Is there an xml attribute I can add, or do I need to create the template as a java configuration to make work?

Comment: What I currently have is a "<rabbit:template id='jmsMessagingTemplate' ...." configuration which I guess I need to convert/incorporate a "<bean primary='true'..." structure?

Comment: `<bean primary="true" .../>` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created [#1701](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1701) to track the naming issue. You should read `rabbitMessagingTemplate` there.

There are several auto configuration instances in Boot that requires certain types to be flagged with `@Primary` if they're not using the "default" name. For instance a `JdbcTemplate` is created for you automatically if none exists and a datasource is present. If you have more than one you should either name one `dataSource` or flag one of them as `@Primary`.

In your case, the messaging auto config for RabbitMQ expects one `RabbitTemplate` to be named `rabbitTemplate` or flag one of the three as `@Primary`.

This is annoying and we should do better. I've created [#1702](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1702) for that.

Let me know if that works out for you. Thanks!

Comment: That is great. I have a watch on the issues and can use Dave Syer's suggestions in the meantime. Thank you much.

Comment: `@Primary` works with spring-boot version 1.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: @Primary save the day!